# why ViewChildren() doesn't work by attribute?

Tags: angular

I'm following this [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) and can't understand why @ViewChildren() always returns with zero elements.

Component:

```
export class InputOverviewExample implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChildren('[ad-host]') entries;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.entries); 
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>
    <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>
    <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>
    <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>
</div>
```

DIRECTIVE:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ad-host]'
})
export class AdDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

this is my demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnhn81?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.ts

notice console.log outputs zero elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
@ViewChildren(AdDirective) children: QueryList<AdDirective>;
```

You didn't add the `AdDirective` to the declarations array. Here's an [Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-view-children?file=app/input-overview-example.ts).

Or you can open the console here to check the list of the Directives [here](https://angular-directive-view-children.stackblitz.io/):

Here's an example on [Angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#example)

Comment: still returns zero - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnhn81-263vkt?file=app/input-overview-example.ts